# I just want to input string and int to some specific array but i got some errors

Tags: arrays, c, input, char, scanf

So i wanna to make a program that if I :

Input : 1 & 2 & 3

Output : & 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char array[5];
   int arr[5];
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       if (i%2 == 0){
           scanf("%d",arr[i]);
       } else {
           scanf(" %s ",array[i]);
       }
   }
   printf("%s",array[1]);
   printf(" %d",arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: Use  scanf("%d",&arr[i]); and  scanf(" %c", &array[i]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using scanf incorrectly.

Write

```
   if (i%2 == 0){
       scanf( "%d", &arr[i]);
   } else {
       scanf( " %c", &array[i]);
   }
```

or

```
   if (i%2 == 0){
       scanf( "%d", arr + i );
   } else {
       scanf( " %c", array + i );
   }
```

Also in the call of printf write

```
printf("%c",array[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take input of a character but you are using wrong identifier.
Instead of this:

```
scanf( " %s", &array[I]);
```

Use this:

```
scanf( " %c", &array[I]);
```